# Wordpress Redirect Function Won't Concate New Query Args with Old

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string, template-redirect

I can't get this function to respect existing query strings. There is a coach=Name query var and the possibility of other query vars like client-status=New as well. I'd like all these to remain part of the query string and append my few other additional query vars.

Am I going through a redirect loop where these are getting washed out? How to stop that? Thank you for any help.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_redirect');

function my_redirect() {
$url = wp_parse_url(get_permalink());
$query = $url['query'];
$coach = $_GET['coach'];
if (isset($coach)) {
    $query .= '&utm_source=' . $coach . '&your-friendref-old=' . $coach . '&your-referral=Referral&your-referral-old=Yes';
    wp_redirect(get_permalink() . '?' . $query);
    exit;
}
```

}

Comment: `if (isset($coach))` makes little sense there, of course that variable is set - _you_ did that, just on the line before. `$_GET['coach']` however might not exist - _that_ is what you need to be checking for.

Comment: And appending values to the query string manually, without even apply proper URL encoding where that might be necessary, is also bad. Make a copy of the existing $_GET array, manipulate your parameters in there, and then feed that to `http_build_query`.